# organising HTML class names and IDs used for different purposes (appearance, jQuery and Selenium)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

There are countless articles on writing clean HTML/CSS.

What I haven't found though is advice on organising class names and IDs that are used for different purposes (design vs jQuery vs Selenium testing).

For any given class name and ID, it's difficult to tell what it's being used for. In 2+ person teams, there also seems to be a tendency to keep adding more and more IDs and classes, and avoiding cleaning up those that are already there, in fear of breaking things.

Are there patterns, conventions, tools, or pearls of wisdom that would help?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based or too broad.

Comment: Referring to the "on hold": When writing my answer, I referred to the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) blog post linked in the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) section of the Help Center. This question sounded like a good fit to me as it is something that I've actively considered when developing (and so must have the OP) and I tried to answer following the six points for _Constructive Subjective_ Qs, but please let me know why if I was wrong so I can learn. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not come across any tools to help with this situation.  But I have used the conventions below with moderate success.  None of them are an exact science though.

### Regarding IDs:

Because IDs are the faster lookup, I tend to use them whenever I'm wanting to address a specific part of my HTML, regardless of how I'm using it (styling/jQuery/testing/etc).

However, because each element can only have a single ID, there's not really an opportunity to use a naming convention or style for different uses.  And I have found that if I've wanted to address an element for one reason, there's a good chance I'll want it again for a different reason.

**For example**: if I have a button on a page and find it using jQuery (by ID) to attach an event handler, then chances are I'll also want to find that button to test its behaviour.

So because an ID can be used for multiple reasons, it should be named in a general way, ideally describing what the element *is* or *represents*, rather than how it will be used.  It should then make sense however it is used.

But as you say, for a given ID

> it's difficult to tell what it's being used for

I agree, and generally don't try to find out unless I have to.  Other team members can't add additional IDs to an element that already has one, and should be encouraged to re-use an existing ID if it fits their purpose.

Using this approach, existing IDs should not be updated or removed, and become a permanent feature of the HTML.  (But like any rule, it can be broken if need be and the risk is worth it)

This way everyone should be comfortable to reuse existing IDs without having their code being broken by someone else changing them, and the ID names should make sense for all uses. This should lead to not having too many "extra" IDs.

### Regarding Classes:

> In 2+ person teams, there also seems to be a tendency to keep adding more and more ... and avoiding cleaning up those that are already there, in fear of breaking things.

My experiences match yours; people tend to add a new class rather than reuse an existing one.  This can also sometimes lead to developers being more comfortable to remove a class if they think they've deleted the only code that used it.  This in turn bites anyone who did reuse the class, and they think "next time I'll just add my own new class to be safe".  A good example of a vicious cycle.

I try to treat classes in the same way as IDs (described above) and:

- Use non-use-specific names
- Reuse an existing class if there's one already there that "makes sense" by its name
- Discourage changing or removing existing classes (to increase confidence with reuse)

With additional thought, an exception could be made for classes added for only "external" reasons, such as testing, by having classes with a common prefix such as "tst".  I would consider this approach if the use:

- Will create a large number of classes (noise)
- Is expected to be changed a lot (as the usage is bedded down)
- Expected to possibly be replaced in future with a difference approach
- Is controlled by an external group to the development team

But using any kind of naming convention is only as good as the people who follow it (or don't).  Testing is really the only way to know if something has been broken when there isn't a compiler to tell you that there's a bad reference hanging around.

### tldr;

So, in general I don't try to organise my IDs and Classes by how they are used, and I try to maximise their reuse and minimise their changes. But I have an open mind if more compelling answers are given to this question!

Comment: Thank you. While there was no magic bullet provided, I can't imagine a better summary of the nature of the problem and how to deal with it as best as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: classes (and targeting HTML elements directly or in combination) for styling, id's for behaviour (and Selenium), "do not repeat yourself/others" thinking - cascading styles, and that is about it.

If everyone follows this concept - common goal to keep clean code is achieved but at the same time it can also mean more problems - for example multiple event delegations (not using "proper" object oriented concepts) and CSS class chains on same element can cause even less readability and more time to handle.

So - actually it is very hard to have a general rule - especially if people have different views and code-styles. But I still think - classes for styling and id's for behaviour applies...